# Numpy - How to select the rows of which the last element is 0?

Tags: python, numpy

I for example have the numpy array:

```
array1 = [[1,2, 3], [2,4, 0], [1,2, 9]]
```

Then I only want to select the rows which don't end with a 0 like:

```
[[1,2,3], [1,2,9]]
```

I tried to do this by:

```
return array1[array1[-1] != 0]
```

But I get a dimension error

```
boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 8 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5
```

I find this illogical because when I had a array of the form [1,2,3,4,0] and I wanted to select the nonzero elements, I could just do `array1[array1 != 0]` and to me it seems both bits of code use the same logic. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `array1` a list of lists or a `2D` numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mistake on your 'return' line.

Try with this:

```
return array1[array1[:, -1] != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, first be sure that you are using a `np.array`. Then you should use proper indexing like `[:, -1]` not `[-1]`.

```py
array1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 0], [1, 2, 9]])
array1[array1[:, -1] != 0]
>>>
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 9]])
```